# Undefined variable: user

Tags: php

Can't seem to find the answer to the problem. I have declared $user as a global variable and later set it by a cookie (if it exists) or by a form then I call the start function. 
Within the start function I echo parts of it but I am getting Undefined variable: user even though I defined it.

```
 <?php
    global $user;
    function ConsoleLog($message)
    {
        echo '<script>console.log("' . $message. '")</script>';
    }
    if (isset($_COOKIE["user"])){
        $user = unserialize($_COOKIE["user"]);
        start();
      }
    else{
          if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
    { 
       $user = array(
       "name" => $_POST['name'],
       "class" => $_POST['class'],
       "school" => $_POST['school'],
       );
       $expire=time()+60*60*24*365;
       setcookie("user",serialize($user), $expire);
       start();
    }
    else
    {   
          echo "Welcome new user!\n<br/>";
            echo '<form method="post">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name">
    Class:<select name="class">
      <option value="9">9</option>
    </select>
    School: <input type="text" name="school">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>';
    }
    }
    function start(){
      echo "Your name: " . $user['name'] . "!\n<br/>";
      echo "Your class: " . $user['class'] . "\n<br/>";
      echo "Your school: " . $user['school'] . "\n<br/>";
        ?>
      <hr/>
      <h2>HomePage</h2>
      <?php
    }
    ?>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Declare $user as a normal variable in your main code; use `global` in the functions where you want to access it.... but better to pass as a function argument

Comment: Just a comment: `submit` is a poor choice of `name` for an element. It causes many issues in libraries like jquery if you use those in the future.

Comment: @MarkBaker that should be posted as an answer not a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usage of global -

```
$user = 'something';

function someFunction(){
  global $user;        // here global will make $user var accessible inside function.
  echo $user;
}
```

If you just want to make variable global, define it outside -

```
define("USER","SOMETHING");
```

Which will be accessed simply by -

```
echo USER;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call the function start() also pass the argument:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE["user"])){
    $user = unserialize($_COOKIE["user"]);
    start($user);
  }
```

Or any where you want to call that function use: `start($user);`

And change the function to accept arguments:

```
function start($array){
      echo "Your name: " . $array['name'] . "!\n<br/>";
      echo "Your class: " . $array['class'] . "\n<br/>";
      echo "Your school: " . $array['school'] . "\n<br/>";
        ?>
      <hr/>
      <h2>HomePage</h2>
      <?php
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't declare variables as global, it doesn't work that way.

Instead, you either need to "import" the variable into each function by putting the `global $user` there, or pass it as a parameter, or store it in a superglobal like `$_SESSION`. As a final resort, you may use `$GLOBALS['user']`, but this is expensive.

Answer (score 0):

if `!isset($_COOKIE["user"])` and `!isset($_POST['submit'])` then `$user` will be undefined. So at the time of `start()` you are referring to keys in an undefined `$user` array.

Also, there is no point in calling `global $user` in the global space, this should be moved in to each function that uses the variable, e.g.

```
function start() {
   global $user;
   // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To do it the way you want to, in each function that you want to use a global variable, declare it at the start of the function.

```
function start(){
    global $user;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code

```
<?php
    global $user;
    function ConsoleLog($message)
    {
        echo '<script>console.log("' . $message. '")</script>';
    }
    if (isset($_COOKIE["user"])){
        $user = unserialize($_COOKIE["user"]);
      echo "Your name: " . $user['name'] . "!\n<br/>";
      echo "Your class: " . $user['class'] . "\n<br/>";
      echo "Your school: " . $user['school'] . "\n<br/>";
          }
    else{
          if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
    { 
       $user = array(
       "name" => $_POST['name'],
       "class" => $_POST['class'],
       "school" => $_POST['school'],
       );
       $expire=time()+60*60*24*365;
       setcookie("user",serialize($user), $expire);
      echo "Your name: " . $user['name'] . "!\n<br/>";
      echo "Your class: " . $user['class'] . "\n<br/>";
      echo "Your school: " . $user['school'] . "\n<br/>";
        }
    else
    {   
          echo "Welcome new user!\n<br/>";
            echo '<form method="post">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name">
    Class:<select name="class">
      <option value="9">9</option>
    </select>
    School: <input type="text" name="school">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>';
    }
    }

        ?>
      <hr/>
      <h2>HomePage</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you confused in this various answers, the simplest answer is as below:

```
<form method="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Write in `form` tag.