# Updating email/password not working, undefined variable

Tags: laravel, firebase-authentication, laravel-blade, laravel-9

I am trying to use a code from https://www.youtube.com/watch v=EM0Wdcux6AE&t=13s&ab_channel=SevenStac , which is very helpful. Although I can't make the updating password/email part.

Error: it shows an error $user is an undefined variable.

I have searched already, tried these:

- [Undefined variable: users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40083342/undefined-variable-users)
- [Undefined variable: user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15729055/undefined-variable-user)

but they're not applicable in my case because I'm using Laravel 9 with Firebase, firestore database.

I also tried doing:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:clear
```

Disclaimer, most of these codes are copied from the youtube video. The login credentials, reset password in email, and register worked but not the updating part.

web.php:

```
Route::resource('/home/profile', App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ProfileController::class)->middleware('user','fireauth');
```

Note: This is the only line that I included because it is the only relevant part. You can ask if you want more.

settings.blade.php:

```
{!! Form::model($user, ['method'=>'PATCH', 'action'=> ['App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ProfileController@update',$user->uid]]) !!}
                                    {!! Form::open() !!}
            
                                    <div class="form-group px-3">
                                        {!! Form::label('email', 'Email ',['class'=>'pt-3 col-12 text-left pl-0']) !!}
                                        {!! Form::email('email', null, ['class'=>'col-md-8 form-control'])!!}
                                    </div>
            
                                    <div class="form-group px-3">
                                        {!! Form::label('new_password', 'New Password:',['class'=>'col-12 text-left pl-0']) !!}
                                        {!! Form::password('new_password', ['class'=>'col-md-8 form-control'])!!}
                                    </div>
                        
                                    <div class="form-group px-3">
                                        {!! Form::label('new_confirm_password', 'Confirm Password:',['class'=>'col-12 text-left pl-0']) !!}
                                        {!! Form::password('new_confirm_password', ['class'=>'col-md-8 form-control'])!!}
                                    </div>
            
                                    {!! Form::submit('Save', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary']) !!}
            
                                    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

ProfileController.php:

```
public function index()
  {
    //
    $uid = Session::get('uid');
    $user = app('firebase.auth')->getUser($uid);
    return view('admin.settings',compact('user'));
  }

public function update(Request $request, $id)
  {
    //
    $auth = app('firebase.auth');

    $user = $auth->getUser($id);
    try {
      if ($request->new_password == '' && $request->new_confirm_password =='') {
        $request->validate([
          'displayName' => 'required|min:3|max:12',
          'email' =>'required',
        ]);
        $properties =[
          'displayName' => $request->displayName,
          'email' => $request->email,
        ];
        $updatedUser = $auth->updateUser($id, $properties);
        if ($user->email != $request->email) {
          $auth->updateUser($id, ['emailVerified'=>false]);
        }
        Session::flash('message', 'Profile Updated');
        return back()->withInput();
      } else {
        $request->validate([
          'new_password' => 'required|max:18|min:8',
          'new_confirm_password' => 'same:new_password',
        ]);
        $updatedUser = $auth->changeUserPassword($id, $request->new_password);
        Session::flash('message', 'Password Updated');
        return back()->withInput();
      }
      return $input;
      
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
      Session::flash('error', $e->getMessage());
      return back()->withInput();
    }
```

Note: in "return $input" it shows an error also, that it is an undefined variable. However, it still worked before when I tried. But when I tried to incorporate my UI with these codes, it did not anymore.

General note: you may be confused that I am using ProfileController with my settings blade, it is because I don't want to move any codes first into my SettingsController, I'm still trying to make it work. Also, it worked before, now it did not.

Comment: you user table has UI column ?

Comment: @UmerFayyaz My user table is in Authentication in Firebase. What do you mean by UI column?